# Question with the "not quite an answer" post notice

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, questions, post-notice

Sometimes overly brief answers will be tagged with a generic message about how they shouldn't be too brief with mostly code as they may not be considered answers in that state.

Here's the message:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and
>   context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is
>   right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations
>   may be removed.

However, this can apparently appear on questions, too:

[Remove Last Comma](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1973/remove-last-comma-problem)

For a start, it says 'answers' rather than posts, but also it's not quite the message that fits questions anyway, even if questions are intended to be tagged with such a message. It should either be reworded for questions or prevented from appearing on questions. Brief code-heavy questions are a different problem to such answers (if they're even seen as a problem, that is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be used for both, but it's usually used for answers requiring certain improvements.  A notice on a question will still generate an inbox notification seeking action, though the OP may not be able to act on it (unless the question can be improved in some way to change the way answers are posted).

As for this particular question, I have decided to remove the notice after editing it a bit.  It's not necessarily different from other questions that also didn't warrant a post notice.  It just happened to be an old question that received quite a few low-quality answers.  It will still remain protected, though.  There still remains an old code dump answers, and I hope this doesn't convince anyone else to post a similar answer themselves.  The newer offending answers have already been deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The warning seems to be intended for all incoming answers on that question. If you read it as such, I would not consider it a bug but a helpful message.

Consider it the moderator version of one of the bounty notifications. Why is the bounty placed? Because the current answers aren't good enough.

*Speculation:*
At some point in time, a moderator encountered multiple answers on such question which got flagged as low-quality or NAA. To help prevent more people from placing answers which aren't considered *good* answers here, a moderator decided to place a note.

I'd say it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).